# Save Multiple Repeats With One Save Action

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have one repeat control on my XPage. I build my repeat based on what the user selects. The repeat control could have anywhere from 1 to 10 items. Each repeat creates new documents.

Is there a way to have **one** save button that saves every repeat rather than having an individual save button in each one?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:repeat
        id="repeat1"
        rows="30"
        var="rowData"
        indexVar="rowIndex">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["1","2","3"]}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:inputText
            id="Number"
            defaultValue="#{javascript:rowData}" />
        <xp:button
            value="Save"
            id="button1">
            <xp:eventHandler
                event="onclick"
                submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc = database.createDocument();
doc.appendItemValue("Form","PersonDoc");
doc.save();

var doc2 = database.createDocument();
doc2.appendItemValue("Form", "PlaceDoc"); // I need the ability to create multiple documents
doc2.save();}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:br />
    </xp:repeat>
    <xp:br />
    <xp:button
        value="Master Save"
        id="button2" />
    <xp:label
        id="label1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[<-- Able to call save once here instead of having to save 3 individual times in repeat?]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:label>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: A code sample would be useful if you can provide one? If your save button is a "submit" button, placed outside the repeats on the page, it should save all data sources at once.

Comment: Hi Brian, I've updated my question with a code sample. My repeat is not tied to a data source as I need to create multiple documents on save. Is there a way I can do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: @RyanBuening Just to clarify: repeats don't save. You want to save values (rendered by repeat) binded to backend documement. But your binding can't work: it binds to row value, which is repeated from constant, therefore it is "read only".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined some CSJS from this stackoverflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10031076) with a remote service SSJS call, and came up with the below, which I think does what you want. But as Frantisek said, using Java beans may be a better solution.

The XPage below has a simple repeat on it, displaying 3 inputs with different values. Clicking the "Master Save" button will pull out the values of all the input textboxes in the repeat using CSJS, then makes a call to a jsonRpcService to run the SSJS that creates the documents. I added lines to pump the input values into the saved documents as well, as an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="rowData" indexVar="rowIndex">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["1","2","3"]}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:inputText id="Number" defaultValue="#{javascript:rowData}" />
</xp:repeat>
<xp:br />

<xp:button id="masterSave3" value="Master Save">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            var domEl = dojo.byId('#{id:repeat1}');

            //Get array of input textboxes
            var textBoxes = domEl.getElementsByTagName("input");

            //Pull out values of the textBoxes
            var valueList = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; i++) {
                valueList[i] = textBoxes[i].value;
            }

            //Call the remote service that runs SSJS, passing in array of values
            var deferred = masterSaveSvc.saveMethod(valueList);
            deferred.addCallback(function(result) {
                //Optional, display an alert upon completion, or perform some other code
                alert(result);
            });
        ]]>
        </xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>

<xe:jsonRpcService id="jsonRpcService1" serviceName="masterSaveSvc">
    <xe:this.methods>
        <xe:remoteMethod name="saveMethod">
            <xe:this.arguments>
                <xe:remoteMethodArg name="valueList"></xe:remoteMethodArg>
            </xe:this.arguments>
            <xe:this.script><![CDATA[
                //For each entry in the array
                for(var i = 0; i < valueList.length; i++) {
                    //Create new document
                    var doc = database.createDocument();
                    doc.appendItemValue("Form", "PersonDoc");
                    //Add current value to the document
                    doc.appendItemValue("Name", valueList[i]);
                    doc.save();

                    //Create another new document
                    var doc2 = database.createDocument();
                    doc2.appendItemValue("Form", "PlaceDoc");
                    //Add current value to the document
                    doc2.appendItemValue("Place", valueList[i]);
                    doc2.save();

                    //Print values to the server console
                    println("value " + (i+1) + ": " + valueList[i]);
                }                       
                return "finished";
            ]]>
            </xe:this.script>
        </xe:remoteMethod>
    </xe:this.methods>
</xe:jsonRpcService>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I think this will work for now. I'm going to check out a Java beans solution for the future.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend to read something about data binding to Java beans.

[http://www.mindoo.de/web/blog.nsf/dx/16.07.2009095816KLEBCY.htm](http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/22.07.2009175255KLELM7.htm)

http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/22.07.2009175255KLELM7.htm

It will help you to gather data from various places on page (repeats in our case) and you need just implement `save()` method to save your data on single button, but to many documents.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I'm going to be looking into this for the future.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a simple action for buttons called "save datasources" or similar. That should save all data sources that exist on the XPage at once.

As an alternative, wrap the repeat control inside a panel. Then use a SSJS like this:

```
var c = getComponent("mypanel");
var ds = c.getData();
```

to get a list of datasources of that panel. 
I know that a datasource object has a "refresh" method, and I assume it has a "save" method, too. So you could get through the list of datasources with a for...next loop and execute the save method of each datasource.

See http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_datasources#Reset+%2F+clear+a+datasource for an example regarding the refresh method.